# how to can load image indicator wordpress website with picasso library in android?

Tags: android, wordpress, android-recyclerview

I want load **image indicator wordpress website any post** in recyclerview by use picasso or glide library and use volley library but I do not know how I loaded the image URLs any post or php codes for load image, please help

Productadapter

```
         import android.content.Context;
         import android.content.Intent;
         import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ProductAdapter extends    RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductAdapter.ProductViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<Product> products;

public ProductAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Product> products){
    this.context = context;
    this.products = products;
}
 View view;
@Override
public ProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
     view = inflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.product_cardview_layout, parent, false);

    ProductViewHolder productViewHolder = new ProductViewHolder(view);
    return productViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ProductViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final Product selectedProduct = products.get(position);
    holder.tvName.setText(""+ selectedProduct.post_title);
   //holder.tvPrice.setText("" + selectedProduct.price);

    String fullUrl = "";


    Glide.with(context)
            .load(fullUrl)
            .centerCrop()
            .placeholder(R.drawable.loading)
            .crossFade()
            .into(holder.ivImage);



   /* Picasso.with(context)
            .load(fullUrl)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.img)
            .error(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_error)
            .into(holder.ivImage);*/
    holder.ivImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent in = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
            in.putExtra("product",selectedProduct);
in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(in);
        }
    });

    //        Intent in = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
    //               in.putExtra("product",selectedProduct);
    //        in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if(products != null){
        return products.size();
    }
    return 0;
}


//ViewHolder class
public static class ProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public CardView cvProduct;
    public ImageView ivImage;
    public TextView tvName;
    public TextView tvPrice;

    public ProductViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        cvProduct = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cvProduct);
        ivImage = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivImageUrl);
        tvName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        tvPrice = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPrice);

    }
}
    }
```

mainactivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

final String TAG = "MainActivity";
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

RecyclerView rvItem;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_antic);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pDialog.setMessage("لطفا صبر کنید....");
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    rvItem = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rvItem);
    rvItem.setHasFixedSize(true);

    StaggeredGridLayoutManager manager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2,
            StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    showpDialog();

    rvItem.setLayoutManager(manager);

    showpDialog();

    String url = "http://10.0.3.2/customer/product.php";
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response);

                    ArrayList<Product> productList = new JsonConverter<Product>()
                            .toArrayList(response, Product.class);

                    ProductAdapter adapter = new ProductAdapter(getApplicationContext(), productList);

                    rvItem.setAdapter(adapter);
                    hidepDialog();

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    if(error != null){
                        Log.d(TAG, error.toString());
                        hidepDialog();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "دریافت اطلاعات با مشکل مواجه شده است!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



                    }
                }
            }
    );

    MySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);


}
```

product

```
import java.io.Serializable;

 public class Product implements Serializable {
  public int pid;
  public int ID;
  public String name;
  public int qty;
  public double price;
  public int user_id;
  public String guid;
  public String post_title;
  public String post_content;
  public String post_name;

}
```

Comment: you want to load image in recycle view using picasso ??

Comment: yes i want  load image any post wordpress website in recycler by using picasso or glide

Comment: in your adapter you are passing empty string in url pass the url in picasso

Comment: String fullUrl = selectedProduct.image_url ; pass url like this in picasso in adapter class

Comment: i know passing empty  string in url ,i can not use String fullUrl = selectedProduct.image_url because i want load image from wordpress database so i can not use your way